# org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied:

Tags: ubuntu, hive, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install Hive 3.1.2 and I followed the steps from https://www.edureka.co/blog/apache-hive-installation-on-ubuntu however while executing the hive command `hive` I get the following error

```
mayureshkadam@mayureshk:~/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin$ hive
Hive Session ID = 4714b76e-acf6-4907-a1bf-0af504a30546

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/mayureshkadam/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/hive-common-3.1.2.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=mayureshkadam, access=WRITE, inode="/tmp":hadoopusr:supergroup:drwxrwxr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1863)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:927)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2915)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:651)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:747)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=mayureshkadam, access=WRITE, inode="/tmp":hadoopusr:supergroup:drwxrwxr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1863)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:927)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2915)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2401)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$27.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:1332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:1307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.createDirsWithPermission(Utilities.java:3668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.ensurePathIsWritable(Utilities.java:4487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:760)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:627)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=mayureshkadam, access=WRITE, inode="/tmp":hadoopusr:supergroup:drwxrwxr-x
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1879)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1863)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:927)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2915)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:660)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.mkdirs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2425)
    ... 20 more
```

I figured out that it is not giving the permission for user mayureshkadam since it is not a part of supergroup..however when I go into opt/groups its there in a group.? what possibly is going wrong? please help me out as I am not sure how to go ahead with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the answer to my question as while the installation procedure of Hive I had not created a symlink of hive as well as the tmp folders which were created were deleted as I had shutdown my PC.
to Summarize I created a symlink using: `ln -s apache-hive-3.1.2-bin hive`
this actually creates another folder wherein all Hive files are stored. And for tmp folders creation I created them using

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /tmp/hive
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/hive/warehouse
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive
```

and that solved my Permission denied problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable permissions control by adding the following to your hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Then you need to restart Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by the `opt/groups` part, but you can add a user to a group using the below

```
usermod -a -G examplegroup exampleusername
```

Also just by looking at your logs

```
Permission denied: user=mayureshkadam, access=WRITE, inode="/tmp":hadoopusr:supergroup:drwxrwxr-x
```

It says the /tmp directory is not accessible by user `mayureshkadam`. You can do either of the below

- start the `hive` process using user `hadoopusr`. Just search how to start a process as another user in Ubuntu and there are many approaches.
- Add user `mayureshkadam` to `supergroup` using the above `usermod` command and try again. I'm sure you will not get this particular failure.

Comment: I found the answer..however what you are saying I had already added the user to the group